# How to overcome the mongoasync callback exceptions

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm unable to enter into the callback method(onResult) and the latch is awaiting endlessly.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue...
My code:

```
public void asyncWriteToMongoForMultiThreaded(String name, List<WriteModel<Document>> documentList, String colName,
            String status) throws Exception {

        final CountDownLatch bulkLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        SingleResultCallback<BulkWriteResult> updateBatchResult = new SingleResultCallback<BulkWriteResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final BulkWriteResult result, final Throwable t) {

                    try {
                        updateStatusForThreads("abc", name, result.getInsertedCount(), status);
                        System.out.println(result +" "+ t);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                bulkLatch.countDown();
            }
        };

        ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
        com.mongodb.async.client.MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = cm.getAsyncMongoClient();
        com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(colName);
        try{
        collection.bulkWrite(documentList,updateBatchResult);
        }catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

        bulkLatch.await();
    }
```